# Export opentelemetry metrics to open search

Tags: opensearch, open-telemetry, opensearch-dashboards, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to export opentelemetry metrics to open search.

My configurations are as mentioned below

```
 metrics-pipeline:
  source:
    otel_metrics_source::
  processor:
    - otel_metrics_raw_processor:
  sink:
    - opensearch:
        hosts: ["https://<domain-name>:443"]
        insecure: true
        username: "username"
        password: "password
```

I was going through one of the data prepper issue and came to know that metrics support is included recently.

https://github.com/opensearch-project/data-prepper/issues/242

I am not able to find proper documentation on this.

In the data prepper pod, getting the below exception

```
    com.amazon.dataprepper.model.plugin.NoPluginFoundException: Unable to find a plugin named 'otel_metrics_source:'. Please ensure that plugin is annotated with appropriate values.
    at com.amazon.dataprepper.plugin.DefaultPluginFactory.lambda$getPluginClass$2(DefaultPluginFactory.java:111) ~[data-prepper.jar:1.5.1]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:401) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazon.dataprepper.plugin.DefaultPluginFactory.getPluginClass(DefaultPluginFactory.java:111) ~[data-prepper.jar:1.5.1]
    at com.amazon.dataprepper.plugin.DefaultPluginFactory.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginFactory.java:62) ~[data-prepper.jar:1.5.1]
```

Appreciate any inputs on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the extra colon at the end of otel_metrics_source , set ssl flag to false and add the index in opensearch section.

Thank you @Karsten Schnitter for your help.

Updated configurations

```
    metrics-pipeline:
         source:
            otel_metrics_source:
              ssl: false
         processor:
            - otel_metrics_raw_processor:
         sink:
            - opensearch:
                 hosts: ["https://<domain-name>:443"]
                 insecure: true
                 username: "username"
                 password: "password
                 index: metrics-otel-v1-%{yyyy.MM.dd}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no section on the opentelemetry metrics support in the general documentation of DataPrepper. You can find documentation within the respective plugin directories:

- [otel-metrics-source](https://github.com/opensearch-project/data-prepper/tree/main/data-prepper-plugins/otel-metrics-source)
- [otel-metrics-raw-processor](https://github.com/opensearch-project/data-prepper/tree/main/data-prepper-plugins/otel-metrics-raw-processor)

There is also a blog post on the [OpenTelemetry metrics ingestion with DataPrepper](https://opensearch.org/blog/technical-post/2022/05/opentelemetry-metrics-for-data-prepper/) in the OpenSearch blogs. It contains a configuration example.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

I am using same configurations but getting the below exception.
com.amazon.dataprepper.model.plugin.NoPluginFoundException: Unable to find a plugin named 'otel_metrics_source:'

Added this exception details in question.

Comment: Your error message looks, as if the plugin was not included in the jar. OTel Metrics support is included since version 1.4.0. The error message indicates you use version 1.5.1. This should include the metrics source. You got a double :: at the end of the line with otel_metrics_source. Maybe this leads to a problem?

Comment: As per this documentation                                                                                              https://opensearch.org/blog/technical-post/2022/05/opentelemetry-metrics-for-data-prepper/                                                                                                                             
double colon :: is required.
Let me check by removing one colon :

Comment: Let me know, if this worked. I think, I have made a mistake in the blog post. I will correct it depending on your findings.

Comment: If I remove one colon : , getting the below exception

     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ssl is enabled, sslKeyCertChainFile can not be empty or null
        at com.amazon.dataprepper.plugins.source.otelmetrics.OTelMetricsSourceConfig.validateSSLArgument(OTelMetricsSourceConfig.java:108) ~[data-prepper.jar:1.5.1]
        at com.amazon.dataprepper.plugins.source.otelmetrics.OTelMetricsSourceConfig.validateSSLCertificateFiles(OTelMetricsSourceConfig.java:113) ~[data-prepper.jar:1.5.1]
        at com.amazon.dataprepper.plugins.source.otelmetrics.OTelMetricsSourceConfig.

Comment: I have added ssl:false for otel_metrics_source: then ssl issue is fixed but getting new exception

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing required properties:indexAlias
        at com.amazon.dataprepper.plugins.sink.opensearch.index.IndexConfiguration.<init>(IndexConfiguration.java:68) ~[data-prepper.jar:1.5.1]

Comment: Did you switch off ssl in the data-prepper-config.yaml as shown in https://github.com/opensearch-project/data-prepper/blob/main/docs/simple_pipelines.md#simple-configuration? Otherwise you will have to configure and provide the certificate to be used.

Comment: Yes, I switched off ssl in config yaml. Now there is no exception during data prepper start up. Can you please help me on how to check the data metrics in open search?
Please point me to any documentation if you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247878/discussion-between-muqthar-ali-and-karsten-schnitter).

Comment: The documentation has been updated to reflect the solution quoted in the answer by @Mugthar Ali.